# converting negative integer to datetime gmt-3 and mktime - php

Tags: php, date, datetime, gmt

**EDITED:**

**THIS PART IS WHAT I NEED TO SOLVE:**

I have a negative integer like: -10800 and I wish to convert this at my local time, which is Buenos Aires (gmt -3).

I'm using an online converter to check what date it is so I can check the results: www.4webhelp.net and it throws that -10800 is Wednesday, December 31st 1969, 18:00:00 (GMT -3) but I believe this is not correct. I was told the negative number is in my timezone which is Buenos Aires.

I also want to create from date to string using the same time format. How can I do this?

**THIS PART IS SOLVED:**

Among the things I tryied in order to do this, a new doubt came up when learning about mktime:

I was trying to know which is the last day for february:

```
$lastday = mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2015);
echo strftime("Last day is: %d", $lastday);
```

And this throws that february has 31 days which is incorrect. Why is that so?

Answer (score 1):

If day is `0`, then PHP takes the last day of the previous month, so

```
$lastday = mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2015);
```

Gives 31st **January** 2015
(0th day of month 2, effectively)

As per the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

> day
>
> The number of the day relative to the end of the previous month. Values 1 to 28, 29, 30 or 31 (depending upon the month) reference the normal days in the relevant month. **Values less than 1 (including negative values) reference the days in the previous month, so 0 is the last day of the previous month, -1 is the day before that, etc. Values greater than the number of days in the relevant month reference the appropriate day in the following month(s).**

(my emphasis)

**EDIT**

If you want the last day of February, use

```
$lastday = mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2015);
echo 'Last day is: ', date("t", $lastday);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, now I understand. But i'm still in trouble with my first question.